# Symfony2 issue variable id with getting objects from database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get from the database `$id` and `$name` but I get this exception:

> The identifier id is missing for a query of Grupa\ProjektBundle\Entity\Car

I have `GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` in Doctrine annotations in entity `Car`.
How can I fix this? The routing matches!

Additionally I have a database entry with an id of 1 and name with the value of some URL that points to an image (http://www.supercarworld.com/images/fullpics/595.jpg).

This is my Controller called **SupercarsController.php**:

```
namespace Grupa\ProjektBundle\Controller;

use Grupa\ProjektBundle\Entity\Car;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SupercarsController extends Controller
{
    public function scAction($id = null, $name = null){
        $car = new Car();
        // $car->setName('http://www.supercarworld.com/images/fullpics/595.jpg');

        // em entity manager
        // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // $em->persist($car);
        // $em->flush();

        $car = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('GrupaProjektBundle:Car')
        ->find($id, $name);
        return $this->render('GrupaProjektBundle:Sc:supercars.html.twig');
    }   

    public function showAction($slug)
    {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('grupa_projekt_supercars',
            array('slug' => 'marka')
            );
        return $this->render('GrupaProjektBundle:Sc:makes.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is my entity **Car.php**:

```
namespace Grupa\ProjektBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Car
{   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    *
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    *
    */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Car
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the `find()` function incorrectly.  Since ID is unique, you really only have to call your method on the ID, like so:

```
$car = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('GrupaProjektBundle:Car')
    ->find($id);
```

However, you *can* still search on both the id and the name if you want to, but you'll have to change your query to:

```
$car = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('GrupaProjektBundle:Car')
    ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name));
```

Comment: Thank you!
I thought about it but in the return.....   render
to type destination of twig template then array with these $id, $name like you did

Comment: No problem, let me know if that doesn't work for you

Answer (score 4):

Just to inform other people about this: I got the same error message when I was trying to call the method find() with a null-value variable.

I was doing: `find($userId)` without realizing that `$userId == null`, and I got the error message that got me to this topic.

Hope it saves some time from someone else